# How To Get Seperate Variables From a For Loop In Java

Tags: java, for-loop, javafx, parameters

Hey I'm currently creating a bracket program however I have hit a snag. In this first class I get the names of each person in the bracket and then in the second class I would like to have access to a separate variable/label for each person. Problem is that I used a for loop and I believe that the only variable being inserted is person. Sorry if this explanation was not great as my coding language knowledge is still beginner.

```
public class EnterNames extends BorderPane {
    public EnterNames(int amount, boolean seedRandom){
       TextField person = new TextField();
       for (int j = 0; j < amount; j++) {
         int teamNum = j + 1;
         if(seedRandom){
            person.setPromptText("Enter Seed #" + teamNum);
         } else {
            person.setPromptText("Enter A Random Team");
         }
         box.getChildren().add(person);
         person.setMaxWidth(500);
      }

      Button submit = new Button("Submit Teams");
      submit.setOnAction(e ->{
          MainScene.mainStage.setScene(new BracketScene(amount, person));
      });
   }
}
```

This is where BracketsScene is declared

```
public class BracketScene extends Scene {
    public BracketScene(int amount, TextField test){
        super(new Bracket(amount, test), 1600, 900);
    }

}
```

Here is the code for the class that I would like to access seperate variables like person1 & person2 ect.

```
public class Bracket extends StackPane {
    public Bracket(int amount, TextField person){
        javafx.scene.image.Image winner8 = new javafx.scene.image.Image("file:src/Images/Winner8.jpg");
        javafx.scene.image.Image winner16 = new javafx.scene.image.Image("file:src/Images/Winner16.jpg");
        javafx.scene.image.Image winner32 = new javafx.scene.image.Image("file:src/Images/Winner32.jpg");
        BackgroundSize bSize = new BackgroundSize(BackgroundSize.AUTO, BackgroundSize.AUTO, false, false, true, false);


        if(amount > 16){
            this.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundImage(winner32, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.CENTER, bSize)));
        } else if(amount > 8 && amount < 32){
            this.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundImage(winner16, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.CENTER, bSize)));
        } else {
            this.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundImage(winner8, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.CENTER, bSize)));
            Label person1 = new Label();
            Label person2 = new Label();
            person1.setText(person.getText());
            person2.setText(person.getText());
            this.getChildren().addAll(person1,person2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your for loop adds the same `TextField` to the same parent repeatedly. You should be getting an exception saying something about "duplicate children", assuming `amount` is ever greater than `1`. Perhaps you meant to add a different field each loop iteration, in which case simply moving `TextField person = new TextField()` inside the loop is a solution. However, you're also adding children to a `BorderPane` via `getChildren().add(...)`. That is not how to use a `BorderPane`. You need to set the layout's properties (e.g. `setTop`, `setCenter`, etc.) only. You also never add your `submit` button.

Comment: It's not clear what you want the UI to look like. For instance, if you want the text fields to be laid out vertically then you need to place them in a `VBox` and then set the `VBox` somewhere in the `BorderPane` (e.g the center). Also, creating a subclass solely for configuration is not typically considered good code design.